# C++ RTP Multicast of a .ts file with SDP error

Tags: c++, vlc, multicast, rtp

I'm using VLC player as the receiver for this RTP stream; under "Open Network Stream" I have

> rtp://@239.255.255.254:49150

I created a udp client with a host ip as localhost with a host port of 49149. I have a .ts file that I read in. I originally tried to split the file into payloads of size 1200 and tried sending it to VLC player but I get this error:

> SDP required:
>   A description in SDP format is required to receive the RTP stream. Note that rtp:// URIs cannot work with dynamic RTP payload format (77).

I'm not sure what the error means and appreciate any help I can receive.

Comment: Your UDP client should have a "regular" IP matching whatever network interface you want to communicate over - don't use localhost (127.0.0.1).  Additionally, VLC will use UDP using the configuration udp://@:<port> .  I'm not exactly sure how your client is implemented but I've gotten regular mpeg streams over UDP to VLC with this configuration.

Comment: I've switched to udp://@239.255.255.254:49150 now which makes the error go away, however, I still do not see the video stream play.

Comment: You need to download wireshark (includes pcap).  You can use VLC to stream out from a specified .ts file.  I'd recommend setting up a VLC client that streams data and a VLC receiver before using your client.  You should be able to observe multicast UDP packets and filter out for whatever type of stream you're using (e.g. mpeg, mpeg2).  With this method, you can analyze and monitor network traffic to determine which end point is at fault.